# Find the range of an expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Given $$E=\frac{(1+x)^8+16x^4}{(1+x^2)^4},$$ Find the minimum and maximum possible value of $E$.

I am trying AM-GM, but I am unable to break it in that format. Also, how do I calculate the lower limit of the expression. Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully $x$ is real, since min and max don't make sense for complex numbers...

Comment: $$\dfrac{(1+x)^8+16x^4}{(1+x^2)^4}=\dfrac{(1+x^2+2x)^4+(2x)^4}{(1+x^2)^4}=\left(1+\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)^4+\left(\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)^4$$   Set $x=\tan y$

Comment: OR set $$\dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)+\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}}2=u$$

Answer (score 2):

$E=\left ( \frac{1+2x+x^{2}}{1+x^{2}} \right )^{4}+\left ( \frac{2x}{1+x^{2}} \right )^{4}=\left ( 1+\frac{2x}{1+x^{2}} \right )^{4}+\left ( \frac{2x}{1+x^{2}} \right )^{4}$.

Note $E(x)\geq 0\ $and $E(x)\rightarrow 1\ $as $x\rightarrow \pm \infty $ so the range of $E$ is contained in an interval and the global extrema, if they exist, will be among the critical points of $E$.

Set $u=\frac{2x}{1+x^{2}}$. Then,

$E'(x)=4(1+u)u'(x)+4uu'(x)=u'(x)(4+8u)=0\Rightarrow u=\frac{-1}{2}\ $or $u'(x)=0$.

The first of these cases amounts to $x^2+4x+1=0\Rightarrow x = - 2 \pm \sqrt{ 3 }$ while the second gives $x=\pm 1$.

Calculating values of $E$ we have

$E(1)=17;E(-1)=1;E(- 2+\sqrt{ 3 })=E(- 2- \sqrt{ 3 })=1/8$ so $E$ has its (only) global max at $x=1$ and global mins at $x=- 2\pm \sqrt{ 3 }$.